# How to Source control SSMS 2016 for free with visual studio online TFS

Tags: tfs, ssms, sql-server-2016

How can I source control my sqlserver db for free? Any solutions except writing scripts or creating the BAK files and restoring?

I would like to connect it to visual studio online ,where the rest of the projects are..

I would like to actually manage the DB scripts DML and DDL and SP etc as the files in VSCode - check in, check out..

How is it possible that Microsoft doesn't have a solution for it?

**So, I tried -**

https://github.com/SvenAelterman/powershell-scripts

Also went through the file manually
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgdef

[image]

How to add the db to source control ?WHere is the menu and connection to tfs ?

Any posts with images on that ?

**Update:
Trying this:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833194(v=vs.100).aspx

Done it:
Got this:
[image]

How about the dml - the data inside the tables?
Is there a way to save that?

Also, if I change some table is it update the sql of ddl of the tables automatically ?

Comment: Look at SQL Server Data Tools.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks. Will check it.
You are talking about integration part of the ssdt - right? 
Can you actually create check in check out experience with it? 
Can you export the db to azure including all and keep it synced with Azure through this?

Answer (score 1):

Source Control integration in SQL Server Management Studio is being deprecated. Please refer to this link for details: [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016)

> Category - Deprecated feature
>
> SQL Server Management Studio - Solution Explorer integration in SQL
>   Server Management Studio & Source Control integration in SQL Server
>   Management Studio"

However the full TFS integrated experience is included as part of SQL Server Data Tools which is designed for a more developer-centric set of scenarios.
So, alternative is to use SQL Server Data Tools and run database development from Visual Studio. Reference this article: [Continuous Integration with SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2017](https://www.sqlshack.com/continuous-integration-sql-server-data-tools-visual-studio-2017/)

Besides, if source code integration is an important aspect of how you use SSMS, you can enable the Visual Studio packages manually. Reference this article : [Source Control in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/11/21/source-control-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/)

Similar threads for your reference :

- [SSMS 2016 Integration with Source Control System (TFS)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c069d843-d7df-455d-9bd5-4955e6e8c650/ssms-2016-integration-with-source-control-system-tfs?forum=sqltools)
- [How do you install a TFS plugin for SQL Server 2016 Management
  Studio?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140602/how-do-you-install-a-tfs-plugin-for-sql-server-2016-management-studio)

Comment: Thanks. Will check it.
You are talking about integration part of the ssdt - right? 
Can you actually create check in check out experience with it? 
Can you export the db to azure including all and keep it synced with Azure through this?

Comment: @TzviGregoryKaidanov Yeah, it's SSDT, It's normal source control, you can put your entire database schema under source control. All database objects like tables, stored procedures and user defined types are stored as individual T-SQL source files inside the project which can be searched and modified in source control just like your code files.whatever, you could check if that works for you.

Comment: Can't figure out how to connect .. WHat menu do you have after the update of that file ?